# Strange profiling overhead for IOArray and STArray

Tags: arrays, haskell, profiling

I'm testing the speed of various memoizing methods. The code below compares two implementation of memoizing with an array. I tested this on a recursive function. The complete code is below

Running the program with `stack test` for `memoweird 1000`, `memoweird 5000` etc, shows that `IOArray` is consistently faster than `STArray` by a couple seconds, and the difference seems to be O(1). However, running the same program with `stack test --profile` *reverses* the result, and `STArray` becomes consistently faster by about one second.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.IO
import GHC.IO
import Control.Monad
import Data.Time

memoST :: forall a b. (Ix a)
     => (a, a)    -- range of the argument memoized
     -> ((a -> b) -- a recursive function, but uses it's first argument for recursive calls instead
       -> a -> b)
     -> (a -> b)  -- memoized function
memoST r f = (runSTArray compute !)
    where
        compute :: ST s (STArray s a b)
        compute= do
            arr <- newArray_ r
            forM_ (range r) (\i -> do
                writeArray arr i $ f (memoST r f) i)
            return arr

memoArray :: forall a b. (Ix a)
     => (a, a)
     -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
     -> a -> b
memoArray r f = (unsafePerformIO compute !)  -- safe!
    where
        compute :: IO (Array a b)
        compute = do
            arr <- newArray_ r :: IO (IOArray a b)
            forM_ (range r) (\i -> do
                writeArray arr i$ f (memoArray r f) i)
            freeze arr

weird :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
weird _ 0 = 0
weird _ 1 = 0
weird f i = f (i `div` 2) + f (i - 1) + 1

stweird :: Int -> Int
stweird n = memoST (0,n) weird n
arrayweird :: Int -> Int
arrayweird n = memoArray (0,n) weird n

main :: IO()
main = do
    t0 <- getCurrentTime
    print (stweird 5000)
    t1 <- getCurrentTime
    print (arrayweird 5000)
    t2 <- getCurrentTime
    let sttime = diffUTCTime t0 t1
    let artime = diffUTCTime t1 t2
    print (sttime - artime)
```

Is there a reason why the profiling overhead is so different (albeit small) on the two array types?

I'm using Stack Version 2.7.3, GHC version 8.10.4 on OS X.

---

Some data on my computer.

Running this a couple times:

```
Without Profiling:
 -0.222663s -0.116007s -0.202765s -0.205319s -0.130202s
  Avg -0.1754s
  Std  0.0486s
With Profiling:
 0.608895s -0.755541s -0.61222s -0.83613s 0.450045s
 1.879662s -0.181789s 3.251379s 0.359211s 0.122721s
  Avg  0.4286s
  Std  1.2764s
```

Apparently, the random fluctuations of the profiler covers the difference up. The data here is not sufficient to confirm a difference.

Comment: I have no idea about what's going on, but I'd start by adding concrete type annotations to `weird`, `memoweird` and `memoweird'`. I'd also check that `-O2` is used.

Comment: @chi The type annotations are trimmed for brevity, but yes they are there. I'll go check `-O2` flag when I'm at the keyboard.

Comment: The types of `memoST` and `memoArray` don't match up with how they are used in `memoweird` and `memoweird'`.

Comment: I do not get a consistent significant difference using the code in this question. Can you post a minimal working benchmark?

Comment: @Noughtmare I did some more serious number crunching. The code is complete now.

Comment: On my side without profiling all the differences are <0.1 if I remove the default `-with-rtsopts=-N` that stack adds in the `package.yaml`. With profiling the differences are a bit larger 0.1 to 0.2, but always positive.

Comment: Also, if I swap the order of `stweird` and `arrayweird` the numbers change inconsistently, so I guess this is also influenced by CPU optimizations like branch prediction.

Comment: If you use [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) for benchmarking, does that have any impact? (Those two cases should compile to almost exactly the same code if everything is working right. Maybe need to change to `unsafeDupablePerformIO` to get them exactly equivalent.)

Comment: Oh, you might also need a change to `unsafeFreeze` to get them to generate identical code. Also, is it intentional that your algorithm depends on lifting constants out of a loop in order to avoid exponential run time?

Comment: @Carl using criterion is hard because the results are memoized, so it will only take a significant amount of time the first time it is run.

Comment: @Noughtmare it doesn't use memorization in any way that interferes with criterion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should use [`criterion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) for benchmarking.

```plaintext
benchmarking stweird
time                 3.116 s    (3.109 s .. 3.119 s)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 3.112 s    (3.110 s .. 3.113 s)
std dev              2.220 ms   (953.8 μs .. 2.807 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking marrayweird
time                 3.170 s    (2.684 s .. 3.602 s)
                     0.997 R²   (0.989 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 3.204 s    (3.148 s .. 3.280 s)
std dev              72.66 ms   (1.810 ms .. 88.94 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 19% (moderately inflated)
```

My system is noisy, but it does appear that the standard deviations don't overlap. I don't actually care much about figuring out why, though, because the code is exceptionally slow. 3 seconds for memoizing 5000 operations? Something has gone horribly wrong.

The code as written is a super-exponential algorithm - there's no sharing of memoized functions in the memoization code. Each sub-evaluation could create an entirely new array and populate it. You're being saved from that situation by two things. First is laziness - most values are never evaluated. The upshot here is that the algorithm will actually terminate, instead of eagerly evaluating array entries forever. Second, and more importantly, GHC does some constant-lifting, lifting the expression `(memoST r f)` (or the `arrayST` version) out of the loop body. This creates sharing within each loop body so that the two sub-calls actually share memoization. It's not great, but it's actually doing some speedup. But it's mostly accidental.

The traditional approach to this sort of memoization is to just let laziness do the necessary mutation:

```haskell
memoArray
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoArray r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n = arr ! n
    arr = listArray r $ map (f fetch) (range r)
```

Note the knot-tying between `fetch` and `arr` internally. This ensures that the same array is used in every calculation. It benchmarks a bit better:

```plaintext
benchmarking arrayweird
time                 212.0 μs   (211.5 μs .. 212.6 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 213.3 μs   (212.4 μs .. 215.0 μs)
std dev              4.104 μs   (2.469 μs .. 6.194 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 12% (moderately inflated)
```

213 microseconds is much more what I'd expect from only 5000 iterations. Still, one might be curious whether doing explicit sharing could work with the other variants. And it can:

```haskell
memoST'
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoST' r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n =  arr ! n

    arr = runSTArray compute

    compute :: ST s (STArray s a b)
    compute = do
        a <- newArray_ r
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray a i $ f fetch i
        return a

memoMArray'
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoMArray' r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n = arr ! n

    arr = unsafePerformIO compute

    compute :: IO (Array a b)
    compute = do
        a <- newArray_ r :: IO (IOArray a b)
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray a i $ f fetch i
        freeze a
```

Those use explicit sharing to introduce the same sort of knot-tying, though significantly more indirectly.

```plaintext
benchmarking stweird'
time                 168.1 μs   (167.1 μs .. 169.9 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 167.1 μs   (166.7 μs .. 167.8 μs)
std dev              1.636 μs   (832.3 ns .. 3.007 μs)

benchmarking marrayweird'
time                 171.1 μs   (170.7 μs .. 171.7 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 170.9 μs   (170.5 μs .. 171.4 μs)
std dev              1.554 μs   (1.076 μs .. 2.224 μs)
```

And those actually seem to beat the `listArray` variant. I really don't know what's up with that. `listArray` must be doing some surprising extra amount of work. Oh well.

In the end, I don't actually know what's leading to these small performance differences. But none of them are significant in comparison to actually using an efficient algorithm.

Full code, for your perusal:

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Main where

import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Unsafe
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.IO
import GHC.IO.Unsafe
import Control.Monad
import Criterion.Main


memoST
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoST r f = (runSTArray compute !)
  where
    compute :: ST s (STArray s a b)
    compute = do
        arr <- newArray_ r
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray arr i $ f (memoST r f) i
        return arr

memoMArray
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoMArray r f = (unsafePerformIO compute !)
  where
    compute :: IO (Array a b)
    compute = do
        arr <- newArray_ r :: IO (IOArray a b)
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray arr i $ f (memoMArray r f) i
        freeze arr




memoArray
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoArray r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n = arr ! n
    arr = listArray r $ map (f fetch) (range r)




memoST'
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoST' r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n =  arr ! n

    arr = runSTArray compute

    compute :: ST s (STArray s a b)
    compute = do
        a <- newArray_ r
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray a i $ f fetch i
        return a

memoMArray'
    :: forall a b. (Ix a)
    => (a, a)
    -> ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
    -> a -> b
memoMArray' r f = fetch
  where
    fetch n = arr ! n

    arr = unsafePerformIO compute

    compute :: IO (Array a b)
    compute = do
        a <- newArray_ r :: IO (IOArray a b)
        forM_ (range r) $ \i -> do
            writeArray a i $ f fetch i
        freeze a


weird :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
weird _ 0 = 0
weird _ 1 = 0
weird f i = f (i `div` 2) + f (i - 1) + 1

stweird :: Int -> Int
stweird n = memoST (0, n) weird n

marrayweird :: Int -> Int
marrayweird n = memoMArray (0, n) weird n

arrayweird :: Int -> Int
arrayweird n = memoArray (0, n) weird n

stweird' :: Int -> Int
stweird' n = memoST' (0, n) weird n

marrayweird' :: Int -> Int
marrayweird' n = memoMArray' (0, n) weird n

main :: IO()
main = do
    let rounds = 5000
    print $ stweird rounds
    print $ marrayweird rounds
    print $ arrayweird rounds
    print $ stweird' rounds
    print $ marrayweird' rounds
    putStrLn ""

    defaultMain
       [ bench "stweird" $ whnf stweird rounds
       , bench "marrayweird" $ whnf marrayweird rounds
       , bench "arrayweird" $ whnf arrayweird rounds
       , bench "stweird'" $ whnf stweird' rounds
       , bench "marrayweird'" $ whnf marrayweird' rounds
       ]
```

Comment: Wow, I'm learning a great deal from your answer. Thanks! It doesn't exactly address my question, but I think it's fair enough to have this accepted.